# Can't exit design mode because Control 'xxxx' can not be created

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

What is the cause of this error and how do I fix it?

[image]

This started occurring on a workbook of ours for reasons unexplained. I made a tiny change to the VBA code behind it, just plotting slightly different values on a chart; everything looks really benign, and definitely not button-related. Why this error, then?

The error occurs only on certain machines, not others.

There is a [Microsoft Dev Center article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251344%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on this error, but it isn't helpful:

> All controls must be instantiated before you can exit design mode. This error has the following causes and solutions:
>
> The control specified in the error message dialog box could not be created. Code can only run after all controls are instantiated and properly connected. Make sure every file needed for the control is available before trying again.

Note that this is a different issue from [the one caused by the Dec 10, 2014 Microsoft Office automatic update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500258/119775); the fix for that one doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe a stupid suggestion, but have you tried deleting and then recreating the control?

Comment: There are many controls; if I delete the one, the same issue occurs with the next. I suppose I could delete them all and start over from scratch.

Comment: OMG I'm getting old... I answered [this very same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23726354/119775) myself 8 months earlier!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple fix for this issue:

1. Close all Excel documents
2. Open a blank document
3. Excel options > Trust center settings>macro settings>Select{Disable all macros with notifications}
4. Active X settings >

   Select either:

   - Disable all controls without notifications
   - Prompt me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions

Apply all settings and close.

Open the affected file and check allow the prompt to enable macros if required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message for Control 'CommandButton13'.  The spreadsheet worked OK on my colleagues PC, but not mine.
I noticed that in the VBA editor, one of the worksheets had somehow had the name changed from Sheet13 to CommandButton1.  On my colleauges PC, we changed the name back & saved the file.  It now works OK on my PC too.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

My answer to the problem was to delete the control buttons from the errored file and then just copy/paste the original ones back in from a previous copy of the file. It seemed to work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Due to a recent Office Update, ActiveX Controls became useless, maybe that's the issue that troubles you.
There ara a few archives related that once deleted and regenerated can solve your problem, if that's your issue.

For more information, you can read this post:
[Bacon Bits: Office Update Breaks ActiveX Controls](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/office-update-breaks-activex-controls/)

Hope it works!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You're right. I've already edited it.

Comment: No, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27500258/119775) is a different issue.